# Know the last modified row or id's row in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm using Mysql 5.5 and by example I have a table like this

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idgroups   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| group_id   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| group_name | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

Where some people are allowed to do inserts,update and delete but I want to know which is the last modified row or row's id in a given time

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: You could create a separate table for auditing, and put a trigger on your table above. On INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, insert a row into the audit table with the affected information.

Comment: You could add a column `updated` on the table. And put the timestamp in that when you updated it.

Comment: Read about `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: This is a great idea, put a column with  a default value to now on insert and update, let try this out

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a second table. something like  `edit_history` for recording modifications. You can put triggers on your `groups` table above that says "Any time a record is inserted, deleted, or updated, create a record in my `edit_history` table".

A trigger can be created as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- For each row inserted
   -- do something...

END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your field is `auto_increment`, you can just select the maximum value of `idgroups` to get the most recently inserted value:

```
select max(idgroups) from tbl
```

to get last modified in general will require additional structure to your table. In particular, if you are deleting, you will need to store what you have most recently deleted somewhere.

Comment: That will give most recent inserted, but not most recently modified.